# write function help in R

Tags: r, write.table

```
> MLest<- arima(X, order = c(1,0,0), method = c("ML"))
> MLest

Call:
arima(x = X, order = c(1, 0, 0), method = c("ML"))

>Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept  
      0.2657    -0.0824  
  0.0680     0.1018  
sigma^2 estimated as 1.121:  log likelihood = -295.23,  aic = 596.47
```

I would like to write the 0.2657 and 1.121 results to an output file.  I have defined a path and file name and here is my codes.

When I use, `write(MLest, file=filename, append=TRUE, sep="\t")` I got the following error:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

When I use, `write.table(MLest[1:2], file=filename,sep=" ", col.names = F, row.names = F)`

It works but I have:

```
 0.265705946688229 1.12087092992291  
-0.0823543583874666 1.12087092992291
```

I would like to have a result as:
 `0.265705946688229    -0.0823543583874666    1.12087092992291` (each value to different columns)

What should I use?

Comment: Why do you plan to use `append = TRUE`? If this is because you are going to print this info many times, why not create a data.frame and print it with `write.table` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

`write.table` is a bit of an overkill for writing a single line in a file. I'd recommend you use `cat` directly on a vector. As you can see from the error message, that's what `write.table` uses under the hood. This works:

```
cat(with(MLest, c(coef, sigma2)), "\n", sep = "\t",
    file = filename, append = TRUE)
```

But I will point out: every time you run this command, a file handle is created, moved to the end of the file, a new line is written, then the filehandle is closed. It is quite inefficient and you'd better open a file connection instead:

```
fh <- open(filename)
for (...) { 
   MLest <- arima(...)
   cat(with(MLest, c(coef, sigma2)), "\n", sep = "\t", file = fh)
}
close(fh)
```

This way, only one filehandle is created and it always points to the end of your file.

---

Alternatively, you could wait to have all your arima outputs to create a whole data.frame or matrix of coefficients and only then print it with a single call to `write.table`.

Assuming you have built a list `ll` of `arima` outputs, you can create and write that matrix of coefficients by doing:

```
output.mat <- t(sapply(ll, with, c(coef, sigma2 = sigma2)))
write.table(output.mat, file = "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 for `sapply(ll, with, c(coef, sigma2 = sigma2))`. The rest is good stuff, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
write.table(unique(as.vector(MLest[1:2])), file=filename,sep=" ", col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

Comment: Please have a look at the editing tips so you can for instance format your code.