# Append header to top of file connection

Tags: r, header

I have a large file which is being read one line at a time in a `for` loop. Because of this if I `write.table` with `col.names=TRUE` I would get `x` number of headers. So I want to add the header at the end (or at the beginning, without having two line on the same line in the output file).

`ifile.valid`: (data.frame)

```
scaf pos Mother Father SNP3 SNP4 SNP5 SNP6 SNP7
HE639   8      0      0    2    0    0    0    0
```

So far I've only been able to add it at the end:

```
#    #for loop going through all the lines, so this has to come before the loop or the first line of #the output file needs to be ignored 
#    o.file.c <- file("testdataout.txt",open="at")
#        write.table(ifile.valid,file=o.file.c, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
#    close(o.file.c)
```

**Edit:**
Here's the file that the above would have produced to make things easier:

[testdataout.txt](http://sdrv.ms/1eBdp7E)

To the start of this file I want to add a header:

```
ofile.c <- file("testdataout.txt",open="at")
ifile.c <- file("testdata.csv", open = "r")
    header<- read.csv(ifile.c, nrows=1, header=FALSE,sep=",") #scaf pos Mother Father SNP3 SNP4 SNP5 SNP6 SNP7
    writeLines(as.character(unlist(header)),ofile.c, sep="\t")
close(ofile.c)
close(ifile.c)
```

Comment: Why don't you write the file at once?

Comment: its too big, so I don't want to load it into memory

Comment: @crysis in its current state your question is difficult to follow and a pain to reproduce.  Provide a minimal working example.  That would mean a dataframe of minimal length (5-10 rows) using `dput(head(ifile.valid))`  I bet you could add the line `col.names= i > 1`.  But currently you've given us too much info (extraneous stuff that only matters to your whole process), while at the same time not giving us enough info (things like data are missing).  I'd suggest a clean up of the question.

Comment: It's not easy simplifying this as its part of a big script. Hopefully the file provided will help.

Comment: @TylerRinker you were right about the col.names. Using `col.names= i < 2` I was able to add the header but I'm getting a warning message now: `In write.table(ifile.valid, file = o.file.c, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE,  :
  appending column names to file`

Comment: When you say "I have a large file which is being read one line at a time in a for loop", you mean "write", right?

Comment: Don't use `write.table`, use `cat`, see this recent question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300249/1201032. For the header, same idea: `cat(header, "\n", file = ofile.c, sep="\n")`. But you need to open the file in mode "w" and write the header first.

Comment: @flodel won't `cat` add the header to the end of the file? By the way anyone know how to get rid of the error?